# alignment for cards inside grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this grid, with each row has 4 columns, each column having one card. html code:

```
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="container mr-3 pt-3 pl-1">
        <div class="alert alert-dark" role="alert">A simple dark alert—check it out!</div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="card p-3" style="width: 18rem;">
              <!-- <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="..."> -->
              <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="55%" height="180" ...></svg>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> <!-- col-sm-3 -->

          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="card p-3" style="width: 18rem;">
              <!-- <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="..."> -->
              <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="55%" height="180" ...></svg>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> <!-- col-sm-3 -->

          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="card p-3" style="width: 18rem;">
              <!-- <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="..."> -->
              <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="55%" height="180" ...></svg>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> <!-- col-sm-3 -->

          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="card p-3" style="width: 18rem;">
              <!-- <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="..."> -->
              <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="55%" height="180" ...></svg>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> <!-- col-sm-3 -->
        </div> <!-- row -->
      </div>
    </div>
```

I want that the row width matches the browser window width, with each card adjusting to allow all of the four fits on the screen (right now, i need horizontally scroll to reach the edge of the row).

anyone knows how to accomplish that?

**update**

the code above is part of this one:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="list-group ml-3 pt-3 pr-1">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Cras justo odio</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Morbi leo risus</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-9">
    ...
    </div>
  <div>
```

Comment: yes, the code I post before is the second column in the update `col-sm-9`. all the content inside this column should fit in the screen without horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `.container` class from the second outer div, it is limiting the width.
Then, remove the inner style of `width: 18rem` from each card.

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="list-group ml-3 pt-3 pr-1">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Cras justo odio</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Morbi leo risus</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="mr-3 pt-3 pl-1">
        <div class="alert alert-dark" role="alert">A simple dark alert—check it out!</div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="card p-3">
              <!-- <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="..."> -->
              <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="55%" height="180" ...></svg>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> <!-- col-sm-3 -->

          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="card p-3">
              <!-- <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="..."> -->
              <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="55%" height="180" ...></svg>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> <!-- col-sm-3 -->

          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="card p-3">
              <!-- <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="..."> -->
              <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="55%" height="180" ...></svg>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> <!-- col-sm-3 -->

          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="card p-3">
              <!-- <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="..."> -->
              <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="55%" height="180" ...></svg>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> <!-- col-sm-3 -->
        </div> <!-- row -->
      </div>
    </div>
  <div>
```

Comment: Ok, I forgot to mention that the code I post before is part of another one (that I just add to the question), where the `col-sm-9` div is the second column of a outer row. the column cannot be `col-sm-12` then?

Comment: Ok, but how exactly you want your column to fit the entire width? That column will not allow this.

Comment: What you mean? the page has 2 columns, `col-sm-3` and `col-sm-9`. inside `col-sm-9` should have 4 columns, `col-sm-3` each, with some space between them. all content should be adjusted to the size of the browser window, with no horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Ok, got it. Editing the answer.

Comment: Removed the `.container` div and the `width: 18rem`, and now the second column (`col-sm-9`) is being display below `col-sm-3`, instead side by side? Tried with 3 and 4 columns inside the outer div (`col-sm-9`).

Comment: All right. Also, I'd recommend to use `col-lg-6 col-xl-3` in the first parent div of `.card` instead of `col-sm-3`.